Iterate files in a folder using dbt and jinja
I would like to iterate through a folder in one of my macros in dbt. Just retriving file names in an array (or any structure) is enough.
Is such thing possible using jinja?
Of all things I tried it seems like jinja cannot access filesystem.

No, Jinja cannot access the filesystem. Not sure what you're trying to read from the files, but the most likely proper way to handle your situation would be to setup your files as seed data in DBT or ingest your files into your database and set it up as a new data source. If neither of these are an option, then you'll need to create a separate job outside of DBT (ie, use Airflow with tasks for your filesystem interaction and then trigger your DBT job)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
